# The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 28081 failed to start in the linux

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I'm doing a spring boot project , and this project can run successfully in the eclipse and war use cmd. However it failed to start in the linux environment.

I have used netstat -ano | grep 28081 , the port is not in use.

```
2019-04-02 05:49:50.628  WARN 25548 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='5ca33035b36bfd63cc6ff647', description='null'}-lswsstpfdb3u.nam.nsroot.net:28120] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:226)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:207)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:154)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-04-02 05:49:50.640  INFO 25548 --- [defaultTaskExecutor-4] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-02 05:49:50.646 ERROR 25548 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 28081 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 28081, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Local war instruction is :

```
C:\tmp\jdk1.8.0_31_x64\jre\bin\java -DaEnv=UAT -Denv=UAT -Da.domainName=pfDomain -Drealtime.nodeName=Node1 -jar C:\aServices.war -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=javax.net.ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\SSL-keystore.UAT.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\SSLTrust.UAT.jks
```

The application can start successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the application.properties file , the ssl location is wrong , it should like this :
 server.ssl.key-store=/opt/a/etc/SSL-keystore.jks
 server.ssl.trust-sotre=/opt/a/etc/certs/SSLTrust.jks